# Create multiple inheritances of Site Content Type in a single List

Tags: 2010, content-type, custom-list

I created a custom List (say `My Custom List`). In `List Settings > Advanced Settings` I have enabled the option of `Allow management of content types?`.

Also I have created a custom Content Type (say `My Site Content Type`) at Site level.

Now I created a content type from `My Site Content Type` by going to `My Custom List > List Settings > Add from existing site content types`. I modified the inherited custom type by adding a new column to it and modifying its name.

But now If I again go to `My Custom List > List Settings > Add from existing site content types` it does not show `My Site Content Type`. It seems a Site Content Type can be inherited (or added) only once in a List. Can we create multiple inheritances of Site Content Types in a single List?

*PS: Apologies if I would have used wrong terms while describing my question as I am still trying to get my head around SharePoint.*

Comment: Did you follow all of the relevant steps in this article :) http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/turn-on-support-for-multiple-content-types-in-a-list-or-library-HA010021562.aspx#BMabout

Comment: @MuhammadRaja: I think I am missing something really basic here. But in my Content Types section it shows me the message `Specify whether to allow the management of content types on this list. Each content type will appear on the new button and can have a unique set of columns, workflows and other behaviors.` and then option of `Allow management of content types? ` which I have set to Yes. That's it! Am I missing something here?

Comment: since we are talking about custom list, why don't you do it programmatically :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543576.ASPX

Comment: @MuhammadRaja: I am a beginner and have just started dipping my toes in SharePoint. :) So I guess there's no way to do this out-of-box. Right?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really logical to add the same content type to the same library more than once.  I would recommend you reconsider how you are using content types.  If you are looking to add the same content type to the same library multiple times and each time modify it slightly then perhaps you would be better creating multiple content types that inherit from the base one.  You can then add each of these separate content type to the library.